# Where is Spring ResourceSupport

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-hateoas

I'm reading Spring in Action 5th. and to add hateoas hyperlink. this class is extending `org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport` however I cannot find it. i'm using Spring Boot version **2.2.5.RELEASE**

```
import org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport;
import tacos.Taco;

@Relation(value = "taco", collectionRelation = "tacos")
public class TacoResource extends ResourceSupport {

    private static final IngredientResourceAssembler ingredientAssembler = new IngredientResourceAssembler();

    @Getter
    private final String name;
```

So what's the name of this class in this version since the source code was using an older versio I think 2.0.2 M1

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Below is from the **Spring HATEOAS** [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/current/reference/html/#migrate-to-1.0.changes.representation-models)

> The `ResourceSupport`/`Resource`/`Resources`/`PagedResources` group of classes never really felt appropriately named. After all, these types do not actually manifest resources but rather representation models that can be enriched with hypermedia information and affordances. Here’s how new names map to the old ones:
>
> `ResourceSupport` is now `RepresentationModel`
>
> `Resource` is now `EntityModel`
>
> `Resources` is now `CollectionModel`
>
> `PagedResources` is now `PagedModel`

So since **Spring HATEOAS 1.0**, [ResourceSupport](https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/0.25.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/hateoas/ResourceSupport.html) is [RepresentationModel](https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/current/api/org/springframework/hateoas/RepresentationModel.html)

Spring also has provided a [migration script](https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/current/reference/html/#migrate-to-1.0.script) which can help in replacing the legacy Spring HATEOAS type references with the new ones.

Comment: Buddy you're a life saver. they should be more people like you in stackoverflow. Thanks & stay safe.

Comment: I hit enter and new cmd window open and closes but nothing changes